# SSIS 2008: Derived Column Transform a String to a Date Data Type

Tags: ssis, ssis-data-types

I had this SSIS package working yesterday and now I'm getting this error with no changes overnight.

Basically I'm getting a String that looks like: yyyymmdd, I need to transform it into a Date Data Type. So I take substrings, to get yyyy/mm/dd then cast it into a Date Type.

The Path:

**Flat File Source ---> Dervied Column ---> All my SSIS package intergration/insertion tasks**

Here are the Expressions:

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],5,6) + "/" + SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],7,8))
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([BirthDate],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([BirthDate],5,6) + "/" + SUBSTRING([BirthDate],7,8))
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([DLIssueDate],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([DLIssueDate],5,6) + "/" + SUBSTRING([DLIssueDate],7,8))
```

Here is the error:

> Error: 0xC0049064 at Extract EXD data
>   from Flatfile into YD db 1, Derived
>   Column [3352]: An error occurred while
>   attempting to perform a type cast.
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at Extract EXD data
>   from Flatfile into YD db 1, Derived
>   Column [3352]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. 
>   The "component "Derived Column"
>   (3352)" failed because error code
>   0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row
>   disposition on "input column
>   "PolicyExpire" (3368)" specifies
>   failure on error. An error occurred on
>   the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at Extract EXD data
>   from Flatfile into YD db 1,
>   SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The
>   ProcessInput method on component
>   "Derived Column" (3352) failed with
>   error code 0xC0209029 while processing
>   input "Derived Column Input" (3353).
>   The identified component returned an
>   error from the ProcessInput method.
>   The error is specific to the
>   component, but the error is fatal and
>   will cause the Data Flow task to stop
>   running.  There may be error messages
>   posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the data you are trying to import is different today. Is there a problem with your text file data source today that wasn't there yesterday?

Answer (score 2):

Your substring paramaters are incorrect for the month and day portions of the date.

For example, it should be

SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],**5,2**)

instead of

SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],**5,6**) 
to get the month value.

The third parameter of the substring function is the **LENGTH** of the substring to find (in this case 2), not the END POSITION of the substring.

Try this

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],5,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING([PolicyExpire],7,2))

(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([BirthDate],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([BirthDate],5,2) + "/" + SUBSTRING([BirthDate],7,2))

(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([DLIssueDate],1,4) + "/" + SUBSTRING([DLIssueDate],5,2) + "/"  + SUBSTRING([DLIssueDate],7,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The transformations above do not take into account NULLs.  Check to see if [PolicyExpire] has a NULL value in one of the records.